# Test pipe delimited format with regular expression in php

Tags: php, regex

I need to verify the string is in the following format, otherwise I need to return a warning message.

> purple|grape juice
>   green|lettuce is good in salad
>   yellow|monkeys like bananas
>   red|water melon is delicious

I need it in the pipe delimited data like above, each line is split into two chunks then a new line.

If there is 3 pipes in in one line, then it is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

This RegEx will validate the whole string to your specs: `^(\w+\|[\w ]+(\n|$))+$`
If one of the lines is invalid, `preg_match()` will return `false`.
*Note: I assumed left part will have numbers and letters only and the second the same plus space*
See it live here: http://regex101.com/r/iV0tC4

So all the code you need is:

```
if (!preg_match($regex,$string)) trigger_error("Invalid string!",E_USER_WARNING);
```

Live code: http://codepad.viper-7.com/i3Hcjs

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to get, but if I'm guessed you need something like this:

```
<?
$lines = explode("\n",$str);

foreach ($lines as $lineIndex => $oneLine)
    if (count(explode('|',$oneLine))>2) echo "You have an error in line ".$lineIndex;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

A RegExp match is all you need. Split the string by new lines, then run the RegExp match on each line, if the match returns false then end the function early (short circuit). The RegExp is essentially START_OF_LINE (^) and anything not a pipe ([^\|]*) and a pipe (\|) and anything not a pipe ([^\|]*) and END_OF_LINE ($).

```
function verify($str) {
    $regex = '/^[^\|]*\|[^\|]*$/';
    $all = explode("\n", $str);
    foreach($all as $line) {
        if(preg_match($regex, $line) == false) 
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

echo verify("bad") === false;
echo verify("bad|bad|bad") === false;
echo verify("abc|123\nbad") === false;
echo verify("abc|123\nbad|bad|bad") === false;
echo verify("good|good") === true;
echo verify("good|good\nnice|nice") === true;
```